# SQL Statement for Accessing Data from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, select, join, union, union-all

I have 7 Tables as per attached following Image.
I will either enter Engine Number or Chassis Number and it should show the respective tables information (these tables have only mentioned fields) so all fields can be shown as result.
I can use hard coded Engine Number or Chassis Number. Every time of execution of this Query, I will hard code the required Engine/Chassis Number and will get the result.
Can anybody please help me to write this query for me?
[Click Here to See the Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXKfQ.jpg)

Comment: The syntax you need is `JOIN`. A good place to start is the info on the [SQL] tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a starting point for your solution.

```
SELECT prod.EngineNo AS engNo, prod.ChassisNo, doral.doralNo [, table.column [AS name]]
FROM DOProductSpecsDetais AS prod
INNER JOIN DORAL AS doral  
  ON prod.DOProductSpecsDetailID = doral.DOProductSpecsID
INNER JOIN DOProductDetail AS prodDetail
  ON prod.DOProductDetailID = prodDetail.DOProductDetailID
WHERE prod.ChassisNo = '<input>' OR prod.EngineNo='<input>'
```

Between the `SELECT` and the `FROM` Statement, you can select any column out of your `JOIN`.

You can cascade as many `JOIN`s as you like...

Which DBMS are you going to use?

One suggestion: Try to simplify the names of your columns, if possible.

One more: If you just started to do Database things, it is always helpful to start a test environment and use a client tool.

Comment: Yes, this works great for me. Thank you so much. I've just added more INNER JOIN for more tables and that's it. Worked Great :)

Comment: However, I have now one more question that what if I want to select only specific fields from tables and not all the fields?

Comment: @adeel, I edited the answer with details in the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

You can write query something like this:

```
select * from 
DoProductSpecsDetail tbl1 inner join Doral tbl2 
on tbl1.DoProductSpecsDetailId = tbl2.DoProductSpecsId
inner join DoproductDetail tbl3
on tbl1.DoProductDetailId = tbl3.DoProductDetailId
inner join ProductColor tbl4
on tbl1.ProductColorId = tbl4.ProductColorId
inner join DoDetail tbl5
on tbl3.DeliveryOrderDetailId = tbl5.DeliveryOrderId
inner join ProductMain tbl6
on tbl3.ProductId = tbl6.ProductId
inner join BPMain tbl7
on tbl5.BusinessPartnerId = tbl7.BusinessPartnerId
```